# Docking lightning components to the bottom bar in Winter '17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, cti

I have a [Winter '17 prerelease org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter17.jsp), and there you can see that Lightning now includes a bottom bar to show the CTI Softphone.

Is it possible to dock lightning components onto that bottom bar? If so, how would I go about it? I'm thinking of something similar to the custom console components in the console, but which would work in lightning experience.

I've tried the [docked composer](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-composer/), but that doesn't seem to work (it docks it to the bottom of your page, but not to the bar itself).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer** - looks like it's something coming in future.

**Long answer**:

The `FlexiPage` object now includes a new type:

> UtilityBar value, which represents a Lightning Page used as the
>   utility bar in Lightning Experience apps.

From page 424.

This then is mentioned in the `CustomApplication` object with a new property:

> **utilityBar**: The developer name of the UtilityBar associated with this
>   app.

Although the ability to create these does not yet seem to have been added.

There is a small mention of it in the UI:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Keats. I will look into the `FlexiPage` and the `CustomApplication` object. The screenshot you show is what we use to display our softphone :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to create the `UtilityBar` pages yet. I've tried to deploy the metadata for a flexipage with modified type of `UtilityBar`; but I can't get it to deploy - need to find out what the page template should be.

Comment: Some good detective work @MarkKeats! This fresh of the press blog will fill in the blanks for you. https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/09/10/unlocking-the-lightning-experience-utility-bar/